# jQuery Autocomplete dropdown to also display what is being typed

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

Just quickly prototyping up a jQuery address autocomplete for a project demonstration.

Basically, when the user types an address the initial input field, it automatically displays a dropdown list of possible addresses (addresspicker-style).

I just need to insert as the first item in the list of addresses "You typed:" to reflect what is being typed in the input box.

See:

http://jsfiddle.net/hotdiggity/NFeEH/

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Autocomplete</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <style>
#results { float: right; }
#address { float: left; }
</style>
  <script>
  $(function() {

    $("#results").hide();

    var addresses = [{
        value: "25/167 Smith",
        add1: "25/167 Smith Street",
        loc: "Brisbane",
        state: "Queensland",
        postcode: "4000"
    }, {
        value: "25/167 Smith",
        add1: "25/167 Smith Street",
        loc: "Mandaring",
        state: "WESTERN AUSTRALIA",
        postcode: "6073"
    }, {
        value: "25/167 Smith",
        add1: "25/167 Smith Creek Road",
        loc: "Werombi",
        state: "NEW SOUTH WALES",
        postcode: "2570"
    }, {
        value: "25/167 Smith",
        add1: "25/167 Smith Street",
        loc: "Collingwood Park",
        state: "QUEENSLAND",
        postcode: "4301"
    }, {
        value: "Level 25/167 Smith",
        add1: "25/167 Smith Terrace",
        loc: "Auchenflower",
        state: "QUEENSLAND",
        postcode: "4066"
    },
    ];

    $( "#address" ).autocomplete({
      minLength: 0,
      source: addresses,
      focus: function( event, ui ) {
//        $( "#address" ).val( ui.item.add1 + ", " + ui.item.loc + ", " + ui.item.state + " " + ui.item.postcode);
        return false;
      },
      select: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#address" ).val( ui.item.label );
       // $( "#address-id" ).val( ui.item.value );
        $( "#address-add1" ).val( ui.item.add1 );
        $( "#address-loc" ).val( ui.item.loc );
        $( "#address-state" ).val( ui.item.state );
        $( "#address-postcode" ).val( ui.item.postcode );
        $("#results").show();
        return false;
      }

    })
    .data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
      return $( "<li>" )
        .append( "<a>" + item.add1 + ", " + item.loc + ", " + item.state + " " + item.postcode + "</a>" )
        .appendTo( ul );
    };
  });
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <p>Start by typing "25"</p>
<input id="address" />
<div id="results">
    <p>
    <input id="address-add1" />
  </p>
    <p>
    <input id="address-loc" />
  </p>
    <p>
    <input id="address-state" />
  </p>
    <p>
    <input id="address-postcode" />
  </p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What they typed will still be in the input box, so what is the purpose of this?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var eladdress = $("#address").autocomplete({
            minLength : 0,
            source : addresses,
            focus : function(event, ui) {
                // $( "#address" ).val( ui.item.add1 + ", " +
                // ui.item.loc + ", " + ui.item.state + " " +
                // ui.item.postcode);
                return false;
            },
            select : function(event, ui) {
                $("#address").val(ui.item.label);
                // $( "#address-id" ).val( ui.item.value );
                $("#address-add1").val(ui.item.add1);
                $("#address-loc").val(ui.item.loc);
                $("#address-state").val(ui.item.state);
                $("#address-postcode").val(ui.item.postcode);
                $("#results").show();
                return false;
            }

        });

var _renderMenu = eladdress.data("ui-autocomplete")._renderMenu;
eladdress.data("ui-autocomplete")._renderMenu = function( ul, items ) {
    $('<li></li>').text('You Typed: ' + eladdress.val()).appendTo(ul);
    _renderMenu.apply(this, arguments);
}


eladdress.data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul,
        item) {
    return $("<li>").append("<a>" + item.add1 + ", " + item.loc
            + ", " + item.state + " " + item.postcode + "</a>")
            .appendTo(ul);
};
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sPyX5/2/)

Comment: I love how in js we access private functions at our will :)

Comment: @BasaratAli In case of jquery ui, it is an accepted way to override the private methods since the demo's itself shows it, You can look at the [category demo](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#categories) to see how they have suggested to override `_renderItemData` method.

Comment: Also there is nothing as a private method in javascript as in java, the `_` is a mechanism to suggest it is not a API method, but an internal one which may get changed without any notice in future versions

Comment: okay : I love how in js we access internal methods at our will :P I am aware of the fact that js does not have private methods. Just that in any `great` language we would have these methods marked private. That was the whole humorous point I was trying to make.

Comment: Thanks but there's a tiny bug. When I continue typing after "25" ie "25 Smith..." no suggestions come up at all.

Comment: that has nothing to do with this issue, even if you remove the changes it won't work because `autocomplete` does not use a token based search